# Autocomplete jquery plugin with select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have two requirements as follows:

1) I am using autocomplete Jquery on select drop down list. I want to show the blank space on first list record(so user can select blank value too) and how to achieve this using autocomplete Jquery? Please check the below fiddler example.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/LfvUz/37/
```

2) When using the jquery autocomplete plugin, what do you do when the user does not select an item in the list, but instead types a valid value and tabs away?

eg when the auto complete list contains:

- ActionScript
- AppleScript
- Asp

Check below Fiddle code

Regards
Vik

```js
$( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );
 
        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },
 
      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
 
        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            classes: {
              "ui-tooltip": "ui-state-highlight"
            }
          });
 
        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },
 
          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },
 
      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;
 
        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .on( "mousedown", function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .on( "click", function() {
            input.trigger( "focus" );
 
            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }
 
            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },
 
      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },
 
      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {
 
        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });
 
        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }
 
        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },
 
      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
 
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
    $( "#toggle" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
  } );
```

```css
.custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label>Select language: </label>
  <select id="combobox">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
    <option value="AppleScript">AppleScript</option>
    <option value="Asp">Asp</option>
    <option value="BASIC">BASIC</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
    <option value="C++">C++</option>
    <option value="Clojure">Clojure</option>
    <option value="COBOL">COBOL</option>
    <option value="ColdFusion">ColdFusion</option>
    <option value="Erlang">Erlang</option>
    <option value="Fortran">Fortran</option>
    <option value="Groovy">Groovy</option>
    <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
    <option value="Java">Java</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
    <option value="Perl">Perl</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
    <option value="Scala">Scala</option>
    <option value="Scheme">Scheme</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello there, I have resolved my first requirement but still looking forward on 2nd requirement. Hope will get reply..

Comment: Finally, I have achieved my both requirements. thanks vik.